# SIGSEV in Singly Linked List

Tags: c++, class, data-structures, linked-list

I am writing a code to rotate a singly linked list counter-clockwise by K number of nodes. I wrote the following code. For example for the input linked list, `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8` the rotate function `Node *rotate(Node *head, int k){}` returns the head pointer to the linked list `5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4`. I wrote the following code. In this code, If I call `print(head)` inside the rotate function then it gives correct output but once it returns the head pointer to main then it either throws SIGSEV or is producing `1,2,3,4`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class List {
public:
    int data;
    List *next;
    explicit List(int element) : data(element), next(nullptr){}
};

List *insert() {
    int n, i, value;
    List *temp = nullptr, *head = nullptr;
    cin >> n;
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cin >> value;
        if(i == 0) {
            head = new List(value);
            temp = head;
            continue;
        } else {
            temp ->next = new List(value);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
    return head;
}
void print(List *start) {
    while(start != nullptr) {
        cout << start ->data << " ";
        start = start->next;
    }
}

List* rotate(List* head, int k) {
    List *traverse = head, *temp = head;
    List *kth, *end;
    int i = 0;
    while(i < k - 1) {
        traverse = traverse ->next;
        ++i;
    }
    kth = traverse;
    while(traverse->next != nullptr) {
        traverse = traverse->next;
    }
    end = traverse;
    head = kth->next;
    kth->next = nullptr;
    end->next = temp;
    print(head);
    return head;
}

int main() {
    int k;
    List *head = insert();
    cin >> k;
    print(head);
    cout << endl;
    rotate(head, k);
    print(head);
    return 0;
}
```

### PS: I am only allowed to change the rotate function.

Comment: shouldn't you change `rotate(head, k);` to `head = rotate(head, k);` in the `main`? or change rotate signature to `void rotate(List*& head, int k)`?

Comment: If `head` gets modified inside the `rotate` function, it should be passed by reference or change the existing code as @user3365922 pointed out

Comment: @Wander3r, Thanks for pointing out, silly mistake :(